# Почему нельзя писать «А, нет, показалось»?

Tags: запятые, орфография, междометие

Почему же-с нельзя писать с запятой внутри, как мне говорил Леопольд?

`А нет, показалось.`

`А нет, это ящерица.`

Леопольд мне сказал, что с запятой нельзя, но почему же-с? И возможен ли вариант с запятой?

Comment: Надо подождать аргументов: сказал, что с запятой нельзя, пусть обоснует.